# Weird Pulseaudio + Bluez interaction error on arch when trying to connect bluetooth headphones

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux

I am on arch linux and wanted to connect my Bose QC 35 II headphones via Bluetooth via bluetoothctl. The behavior is very weird. I can issue the pair command without any problems. Then I issue the connect command. I get audio feedback from the headphones that they have connected. After ~ 6 seconds the headphones disconnect again.

#### System Config

```
bluetoothctl: 5.71
pulseaudio 16.1
extra/bluez 5.71-2
Bluetooth adapter: ISY IBT-1000 5.0
```

As advised, I have put `ControllerMode = bredr` in my /etc/bluetooth/main.conf (from https://flx.ai/2019/bose-qc35ii-linux#deactivate-bluetooth-le)

#### Runtime Errors

This is the output when I run the bluetoothctl commands:

```
CHG] Device 04:52:C7:7B:4F:43 Connected: yes
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep3
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep1
<SNIP>
/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep51
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep19
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep49
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep17
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep33
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/sep1/fd0
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_7B_4F_43/player0 [default]
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# Agent unregistered
[Bose QuietComfort 35]# [DEL] Controller 00:0A:CD:42:F7:50 archdesktop [default]
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
```

Maybe more important is the journal -xfe output:

```
Dec 29 12:44:12 archdesktop pulseaudio[67328]: Daemon already running.
Dec 29 12:44:19 archdesktop pulseaudio[67151]: Battery Level: 90%
Dec 29 12:44:19 archdesktop pulseaudio[67151]: Dock Status: undocked
Dec 29 12:44:27 archdesktop pulseaudio[67151]: org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.UnregisterBatteryProvider() Failed: org.bluez.Error.DoesNotExist:Provider does not exist
```

The last error hints at something being wrong with the bluez battery component. I thought about just patching the code out but I don't have the skills to do that on my system and I don't know if this will break other stuff

Does anyone know what I could try next?